# How programs determine which language to install in on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, locale, localization

I have installed `Geany IDE` and `Microsoft R Open` on my Windows 7 64-bit computer which has Windows in English and some of the localization settings set to Turkish format and it has a Turkish IP. When I installed these two programs they installed a Turkish GUI without prompting me. I actually wanted to install the international versions of these programs and I really wonder which setting I should change to achieve this effect.

Okay not all of the software changed language, yet I am presenting a screenshot of the current situation. In this screenshot the area in the red box is in Turkish, whereas the area in the green box is in English(it used to be Turkish too before changing the settings). Why this might be the case?
In the screenshot you can also see with which settings I have played.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows API (which the installers use) has a function which can be used to determine which locale the system is configured to use.

The IP address has no role in this whatsoever. Most installers do ask you for language during install if you choose the "Custom Install" or "Expert Install" or something similar. I daresay the program itself must also have an option to change the language.

If your installer and program do not provide this choice, set your locale to US English and then install the program. Revert once you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and update you. What do you exactly mean by the locale? The programs do not provide this option in custom installation and it is not easy to change it after installation.

Comment: It is a set of parameters that defines the user's language, region and any special variant preferences that the user wants to see in their user interface.

Comment: Is it accessible via the Control Panel?

Comment: Yes. There is a category in the Control Panel which allows you to change your time, language and region.

Comment: I managed to change it at last; one of the variables under the Control Panel -> Region and Language controls this feature.

Comment: Actually not all of the program changed language which is really weird. By the way Microsoft R Open GUI changed language automatically without reinstallation.

Comment: It's weird indeed for two languages to co-exist. Have you uninstalled/reinstalled after changing the locale?

Comment: Might as well have something to do with AppData which wasn't deleted.

Comment: AppData was the culprit removing it remedied the situation.